# looking for the reason for NPE in LinuxNetworkParams.getDomainName call

Tags: java, unix, oshi

We are seeing the NPE in the LinuxNetworkParams.getDomainName call in oshi version 6.1.6. Although I am not able to see any reason for this. Can anyone help me when with the reasons why this can throw NPE?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at oshi.software.os.linux.LinuxNetworkParams.getDomainName(LinuxNetworkParams.java:80) ~[oshi-core-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
at com.airwatch.common.diagnostics.DiagnosticCollector.fetchSystemConfiguration(DiagnosticCollector.java:148) ~[diagnostic-library-2.0.3.jar!/:?]
```

Here is the code for the method :
https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/oshi-parent-6.1.6/oshi-core/src/main/java/oshi/software/os/linux/LinuxNetworkParams.java#L79-L80

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `info.ai_canonname` is `null`, Try adding null check for `ai_canonname` or use null safe way to do trim like `StringUtils.trim()`

```
public static String trim(final String str) {
    return str == null ? null : str.trim();
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this queries for a PTR record but not all hosts have them

Answer (score 1):

As @Jishnu-Prathap said in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74345429/1161484), `info.ai_canonname` is null.

This value normally returns the "official name of the host" in response to the [`getaddrinfo()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) function whose docs state:

> If `hints.ai_flags` includes the `AI_CANONNAME` flag, then the `ai_canonname` field of the first of the `addrinfo` structures in the returned list is set to point to the official name of the host.

This may represent an error in your server configuration; fixing the "official name of the host" will prevent the NPE if you keep the same OSHI version.

However, failing to null-check this value was a bug in earlier versions of OSHI but was [fixed in version 6.2.2](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/pull/2133) and upgrading will also prevent the NPE (but not give you a canonical host name, since it doesn't exist!)